# Is BagOfBagsConcat a necessary UDF? or is it bad form?

Tags: apache-pig

I've managed to get myself a bag of bags, where each inner bag contains the same form of tuples: `{({(cow,30),(monkey,20)}),({}),({(duck,3)})}`

So I created a UDF called BagOfBagsConcat that expects as a parameter this exact situation: a single bag that contains homogeneous bags and returns as its output:
`{(cow,30),(monkey,20),(duck,3)}`

I've looked around and I found only BagConcat in datafu. Is that a sign that this function isn't really necessary and that a bag of bags is just a freak of nature, and I must re-review my pig script?

Thanks, and let me know if I need to specify the pig script that created this in order to be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops. sometimes left-join is better than cogroup. This created a bag of bags:

```
final_output = cogroup final_output by nodeid, new_edges by nodeid1;
final_output = foreach final_output generate flatten($1.hash_id) as hash_id, new_edges;
final_output = cogroup nodes_per_entity by hash_id, final_output by hash_id;
```

so I changed it to:

```
final_output = join final_output by nodeid left, new_edges by nodeid1;
final_output = group final_output by hash_id;
final_output = foreach final_output generate group as hash_id, 
    final_output.(nodeid1, nodeid2, edge_pit, asset_id1, asset_id2) as new_edges;
```

and now it's an ordinary bag of tuples (albeit some of them have empty values due to the left join, but that's easier to handle).

Answer (score 1):

It's not that uncommon.  We've run into this too so we added a [BagUnion](https://github.com/linkedin/datafu/blob/master/src/java/datafu/pig/bags/BagUnion.java) to DataFu for the next version.  As you describe it is like BagConcat except it operates on a bag of bags instead of a tuple of bags.